Importing modules from specific folder in Blender python script (MacOS)
In a script within a .blend file, I'm trying to import modules from a folder relative to that blend file.
This is my folder structure:

Models/

model.blend
_scripts/

color-thief-py-master/

colorthief.py


...other python module repositories here




model.blend has this code at the top of one of its scripts:
from os.path import dirname as up

packages_path = os.path.join(up(bpy.data.filepath), "_scripts")

if (not packages_path in sys.path):
    sys.path.insert(0, packages_path)

When I try to import colorthief afterwards (from colorthief import ColorThief) I get a ModuleNotFoundError. Same goes for all other modules in the scripts/ folder.
I have checked that the _scripts folder is being successfully added to the path.
What am I doing wrong here? I'm on MacOS but ideally looking for a cross-platform solution.

Do you have an __init__.py in the package folders? Without one Python won't recognize those directories as importable.

The problem is that when you use sys.path.insert(0, packages_path) the system file becomes in the folder Models. Try this:
from _scripts.color-thief-py-master.colorthief import ColorThief

or import ColorThief before using sys.path.insert(0, packages_path)

Thank you- this was what helped, in a roundabout way. It never occurred to me that the directory name was what came after from. My import statement was still using the old name of the package folder (colorthief) instead of the updated name of the folder.
